# DataGrid override default CTRL+DOWN ARROW behavior

Tags: wpf, datagrid

The default WPF DataGrid CTRL+DOWN ARROW behavior will moves the focus to the last cell in the current column. I just want to override that style to work with following functionalities :

1) CTRL + KEY DOWN - Move to next row without selecting that row. Only the row header template is selected(to get a feeling that the user is on next row).

2) Hitting SPACE bar will select that row

I found these functionalities working in XCEED Extended WPF Toolkit DataGrid. But now I'm in a stage where I can't replace the default DataGrid with XCEED. So how can I include this functionalities in default DataGrid.

I tried to focus the next row on `PreviewKeyDown` Event. But couldn't find any methods or properties. Does anyone have idea to handle this scenario?

Comment: Could post the code in you PreviewKeyDown handler? I would have tried capturing those key combinations, and setting the desired effect in response. Then tried porting that back into the XAML using triggers. I'm guessing this is what you tried?